# Missing Eyeshot register in the toolbox

Tags: eyeshot

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 at this time.
After Installation of Eyeshot Pro 2021 there is no entries in the toolbox.
The strange thing is, that a manual insert does'nt work.
If I rename a register in Eyeshot Professional 2021 there is mentioned that the register allready exists.

So, how can I get the controls into my toolbox.

Regards Jürgen

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes because this questions seems beyond the scope or off topic of StackOverflow which is a place for programming or code level type questions. Seems like you would get better support in the VIsual Studio forums actually.

Answer (score 0):

Eyeshot 2021 is targeting .net framework 4.8. Maybe Visual Studio purposed an earlier version instead. Try checking the target framework of your project.